# DatabaseError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied

Tags: pandas, sqlite

I am trying to query from a large csv file; I am showing the first three rows:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('crime.csv', nrows=3); df
```

[image]

because of memory limitation, I first create db file and then query from there as below:

```
import sqlite3

db = sqlite3.connect("crime.sqlite")

for chunk in pd.read_csv('crime.csv', chunksize=1000):
    chunk.to_sql("crime", db, if_exists="append")
    
db.execute("CREATE INDEX NEIGHBORHOOD_ID on crime(NEIGHBORHOOD_ID)")
db.close()
```

Here I define a function to read from the newly created .sqlite and query on that:

```
def crime_neighbor(neighbor_id):
    conn = sqlite3.connect("crime.sqlite")
    q = "SELECT * FROM crime WHERE NEIGHBORHOOD_ID = ?"
    values = (neighbor_id,)
    return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn, values)
```

when I run `crime_neighbor("cbd")`, I get the following error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT * FROM crime WHERE NEIGHBORHOOD_ID = ?': Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

I tried changing `values = (neighbor_id,)` to `values = [neighbor_id,]` but the error remains the same.

Comment: You forgot to tell `read_sql_query`where to find the `params`. Review the function signature and arguments [in the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html)

Comment: @DinoCoderSaurus thanks; it worked after i explicitly assign the values to params argument :  `return pd.read_sql_query(q, conn, params=values)`

Comment: can you answer the question so I can close this post? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the syntax of `pd.read_sql_query(q, conn, values)`. It doesn't actually *send* the parameters. Review the function signature and arguments [in the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html).